# Swift generic function calling function with return type overload

Tags: swift, generics

just a quick question. I have the following code, which works just fine:

```
class obA: Printable {
    var description: String { get { return "obA" } }
}

class obB: Printable {
    var description: String { get { return "obB" } }
}


func giveObject() -> obA { return obA() }
func giveObject() -> obB { return obB() }

var a: obA = giveObject()
var b: obB = giveObject()

println(a)
println(b)
```

The right variant of giveObject is being called and all is well. Of course this is just a simplified case, in reality in my project there are several dozens of overloads of 'giveObject', all differing in return type. Now, I want to make a generic function to parse all these things. So, next step:

```
func giveGeneric<T>() -> T {
    return giveObject()
}

var c: obA = giveGeneric()
println(c)
```

And this complains about ambiguous use of giveObject. I can understand where the error comes from, but I don't see right away how I can solve it and use a construct like this...

Comment: It's an interesting question, and there are plenty of answers on StackOverflow about instantiating a class from its (String) name, but I fail to see your need, here, without more detail - at the point where you say `var x: ObX = giveObject()` you could equally well say `var x = ObX()` ...

Comment: Of course this is a simplified example. The giveGeneric function is supposed to do some processing that can not be done in giveObject, but is the same for a lot of different types, with just the type different. I'm trying to reduce a lot of duplicate code in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all just a note.

If the generic type of `giveGeneric` is simply `T`, then it can be anything (a String, an Int, ...). So how should `giveObject()` react in this case?

I mean, if you write:

```
let word : String = giveGeneric()
```

internally your generic function calls something like:

```
let result : String = giveObject() // Ambiguous use of giveObject
```

### My solution

I declared a protocol as follow:

```
protocol MyObject {
    init()
}
```

Then I made your 2 classes conform to the protocol

```
class obA: Printable, MyObject {
    var description: String { get { return "obA" } }
    required init() {}
}

class obB: Printable, MyObject {
    var description: String { get { return "obB" } }
    required init() {}
}
```

Finally I can write this

```
func giveGeneric<T:MyObject>() -> T {
    return T()
}
```

Now I can use it:

```
let a1 : obA = giveGeneric()
let b1 : obB = giveGeneric()
```

You decide if this is the solution you were looking for or simply a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

That cannot work, even if you implement a `giveObject` function for any possible type. Since `T` can be any type, the `giveGeneric` method cannot determine the correct overload to invoke.

The only way I can think of is by creating a huge swift with as many cases as the number of types you want to handle:

```
func giveGeneric<T>() -> T? {
    switch "\(T.self)" {
    case "\(obA.self)":
        return giveObject() as obA as? T
    case "\(obB.self)":
        return giveObject() as obB as? T
    default:
        return .None
    }
}
```

But I don't think I would use such a solution even with a gun pointed at my head - it's really ugly.

If in all your cases you create instances using a parameterless constructor, then you might create a protocol and constraint the `T` generic type to implement it:

```
protocol Instantiable {
    init()
}

func giveGeneric<T: Instantiable>() -> T {
    return T()
}
```

You can use with built-in as well as new types - for instance:

```
extension String : Instantiable {
    // `String` already implements `init()`, so nothing to add here
}

let s: String = giveGeneric()
```

Alternatively, if you prefer you can make the protocol declare a static `giveObject` method rather than a parameterless constructor:

```
protocol Instantiable {
    static func giveObject() -> Self
}

func giveGeneric<T: Instantiable>() -> T {
    return T.giveObject()
}

extension String : Instantiable {
    static func giveObject() -> String {
        return String()
    }
}

let s: String = giveGeneric()
```

Comment: It's too bad I can accept only one answer. Both yours and @appzYourLife 's answers helped me find the solution.

Comment: What's important is that your problem is solved, isn't it? :)

Comment: @appzYourLife it was just a couple minutes... I just typed a little faster ;-) Our answers are equivalent, and I'm ok with yours selected as the solution.